# What are the different types of Degrees, Diplomas and Certifications and Industry types?

Tags: data-request, education

What are all the different types of Degrees, Certifications and Diplomas you can get? I can find the Types of Degrees, but I am not looking only for the types of degrees.

I am looking for Certificate types and Diploma types, i.e: `National Diploma` or `Senior Certificate` or for the degree: `Bachelor of Arts`.

Comment: Are you looking for open data about the requirements or attributes about these various degrees?

Comment: Im looking for the names of the various degrees, so I guess that would be open data. I'm not looking for only degrees, as I said above Diplomas and Certificates also...

Comment: If you're only looking for *accredited* degrees and certifications, you might be able to get those lists from the organizations that audit the institutions.  For instance, [Middle States](http://www.msche.org/) lists in the 'details' section for each institution the degrees they offer, but it's really general (eg, 'Master's' but not 'Master of Arts')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you are after, but in any case, looking at the ESCO-standard would probably get you in the right direction.

[ESCO](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=1042&langId=en) is a EU-standard published in October, linking the NACE sector classification, the ISCO occupational standard and the EQF qualifications standard.

For instance the information about the [European Hairdressing Certificate](https://ec.europa.eu/esco/web/guest/qualification/-/Qualification/nl/nl/nl/http://ec.europa.eu/esco/qualification/23887?resetLanguage=true&newLanguage=en)  contains standardized metadata about the awarding bodies, the corresponding qualifications, the related occupations, etc.

The complete standard is available as open data, and can be [downloaded](https://ec.europa.eu/esco/download) as RDF.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I followed the download link and it is more or less what I was looking for...