# looking for a list of certifications and licences relevant for US jobs

Tags: data-request, education, labor

A similar question has been asked here: [What are the different types of Degrees, Diplomas and Certifications and Industry types?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1432/4221), but the answer refers to a EU site, and the certifications are different in the two markets.